# Get Static referenced files with http request in meteor

Tags: meteor

This can be a silly question but I have had some issues with it. I am trying to implement jwplayer with meteor. Jwplayer will try to get a file based off the url you suggest. So I tried to place a file in localhost:3000/test.mp3. When I tried to hit that url I get just the default site. This would work if I used tomcat. Is there something I can do to get the files relative to meteor directory?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can put your static file into root\public\test.mp3, then you can access it with http://localhost:3000/test.mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `/public` directory, [per the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp):

> Lastly, the Meteor server will serve any files under the public directory, just like in a Rails or Django project. This is the place for images, favicon.ico, robots.txt, and anything else.

Meteor hasn't yet implemented server side routing and all directories are ultimately flattened. So for the time being, you can access your file at `http://localhost:3000/test.mp3`, but that may change in the future.

Comment: Don't forget that any file you put into the `/public` will be bundled for production. So if you put big files there ...